# How to delete rows from a matrix that contain more than 50% zeros MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I want to remove the rows in an array that contain more than 50% of null elements.

eg:
if the input is

```
1 0 0 0 5 0
2 3 5 4 3 1
3 0 0 4 3 0
2 0 9 8 2 1
0 0 4 0 1 0
```

I want to remove rows 1 and 5, but retain the rest. The output should look like:

```
2 3 5 4 3 1
3 0 0 4 3 0
2 0 9 8 2 1
```

I want to do this using matlab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use logical indexing into the rows, based on the mean of the rows of `A` negated:

```
t = .5; % threshold
A(mean(A==0,2) > t, :) = [];
```

What this does:

- Compare `A` with `0`: turns zeros into `true`, and nonzeros into `false`.
- Compute the mean of each row.
- Compare that to the desired threshold.
- Use the result as a logical index to delete unwanted rows.

Equivalently, you can keep the wanted rows instead of removing the unwanted ones. This may be faster depending on the proportion of rows:

```
A = A(mean(A~=0,2) >= 1-t, :);
```

Comment: What if I want to change the threshold to a different percentage? Say 40% or 30%?

Comment: In the first code snippet, change `.5` by the desired threshold. In the second, use 1 minus the threshold

Comment: Clever! It's worth noting that this could potentially incur a significant memory penalty if `A` is large, since an intermediate logical matrix of the same size as `A` needs to be created for the indexing. The compiler may (now or in the future) optimize this away but it's food for thought for the general audience. An explicit loop with [`nnz`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html) should avoid this at the expense of the twitter compactness.

Comment: This is a pedantic, but if you happen to have `NaN` values in your data, `~A` will error.  It's a little safer to use `A == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [standardizeMissing function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/standardizemissing.html) and [rmmissing function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rmmissing.html) together to achieve this:

```
>> [~,tf] = rmmissing(standardizeMissing(A,0),'MinNumMissing',floor(0.5*size(A,2))+1);
>> A(~tf,:)
```

The call to `standardizeMissing` replaces the `0` values with `NaN` (the standard missing indicator for double), then the `rmmissing` call identifies in the logical vector `tf` the rows that have more than 50% of their entries as `0` (i.e., those rows that have more than `floor(0.5*size(A,2))+1` 0-valued entries. Then you can just negate the `tf` output and use it as an indexer.  You can adapt the minimum number missing easily to satisfy whatever percentage criteria you want.

Also note that `tf` is a logical vector here that is only the size of the number of rows of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

As I [mentioned on Luis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667547/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-matrix-that-contain-more-than-50-zeros-matlab#comment74388460_43667577), one downside to his approach is that it requires an intermediate logical array of the same size as `A` to be created, which can potentially incur a significant memory/performance penalty when working with large arrays.

An explicit looped approach with [`nnz`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html) (overly verbose, for clarity):

```
[nrows, ncols] = size(A);
maximum_ratio_of_zeros = 0.5;
minimum_ratio_of_nonzeros = 1 - maximum_ratio_of_zeros;
todelete = false(nrows, 1);
for ii = 1:nrows
    if nnz(A(ii,:))/ncols < minimum_ratio_of_nonzeros
        todelete(ii) = true;
    end
end
A(todelete,:) = [];
```

Which returns the desired answer.